# MS SQL 2014 REPLACE Заменить спецсимвол в поле

Tags: sql, sql-server

Не получается заменить спецсимвол `[` в строке. Причем найти спецсимвол во вложенной выборке можно, для этого есть специальная конструкция `ESCAPE`, но она работает только с `LIKE`. Буду рад услышать какие-нибудь предложения на этот счет.

```
update NewSampleResponse
set comment = replace(comment, '[', '(')
where id in (SELECT id
              FROM NewSampleResponse
              where comment like('%\[%') escape '\')
```

Ошибка:

> Тип данных аргумента text недопустим для аргумента 1 функции replace.

Есть идея записать символ в бинарном виде, но не соображу как это сделать...

Comment: Разве просто так не работает? 
update NewSampleResponse
set comment = replace(comment, '[', '(')

Comment: Не используйте устаревший тип TEXT. Замените его на varchar(max), если размер столбца превышает 8000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Действительно, оказалось все проще, поле текстовое поэтому REPLACE с ним не работает.
Просто comment нужно обернуть: CAST(comment AS varchar(MAX))